# How to scrape data every hour in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I currently have a `node js` application that is hosted on `Heroku` that scrapes data from a certain website but I can't seem to figure out how it can scrape data every hour without me refreshing the application. Or am I missing the point totally and do I need something else to do this?

```
function updateEveryHour() {
    getData(); // init
    setInterval(() => {
        getData();
    }, 10000 * 60 * 60); // every hour
}

updateEveryHour();
```

So currently this does work when I'm running the app local, but when I build it to Heroku and, for example, wait few hours then nothing has happened. (nothing has been added to my database). Unless I refresh my page on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of use case, I'd suggest you look up a scheduler like Heroku Scheduler or similar. Scheduled jobs like this shouldn't be called from the frontend, as you saw it's unrealistic to have the application running for an extended period of time.

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler